# Power Automate, exporting SP list to CSV, format issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I am trying to export my SP list to csv, however it exports in an odd format.

My flow isnt really exporting the list in easy to read values. My expected values shouldn't look like this :

[image]

my flow looks like:

[image]

How can I fix this to get the exact values from my SP list?

Comment: I am brand new to Power Automate and am having trouble generating CSV file content from [Seus Shaders](https://www.seusshaders.org/) lists where fields contain multiple choices, or the names of people selected from Active Directory. The resulting file contains JSON in each column instead of the multiple-choice text items separated by commas. How do I solve this issue on [Sazinjector](https://sazinjector.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please follow the steps:**

1.On the Create CSV table action, click "**Show advanced options**"

[image]

2.Change the value of the **Columns** field to **Custom**

[image]

3.Enter the corresponding Header and Value

**For example:**

- Title >> Title
- Modified >> Modified
- Created >> Created
- Author >> Created By
- Author#Name >> Created By DisplayName
- Author#Email >> Created By Email

[image]

4.Save and Test this flow

[image]

[image]

=========================== **Updated Answer** ========================

These are not random nonsense, but Odata sentences. Because [**Created By**] is a "Person or Group" column, it contains DisplaName, Email, Claim and other information.

So if you expand to look at the information, you will find that he will display all the data about the **[Created By]** column

[image]

Comment: thanks, this is helpful. But why all that random gibberish in your author column? I have that in some of mine too.

Comment: Hi Jonnyboi. I have updated the reason for this “random gibberish” information in my initial answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!

Comment: Hi Jonnyboi. If the answer is helpful to you, you can accept it as answer. The behavior will help others who meet the similar issue in the future quickly find the correct answer.